# Battleship game: how can I check if user input is in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, user-input, list-comprehension

I am creating a battleship-like game, where I have to check if the user has hit a ship or not.I am trying to check if an input is part of a list of x,y coordinates for 8 ships (battleship). 
My big list of lists is like:

```
 ships = [ship1][ship2][ship3] and so on (6 ships).
```

The list for each ship is:

```
ship1 = ['7','6,]['2','5']['3','8']
```

and so on.

So far I am using :

```
if input[0] ==ship1[0] and input[1] == ship1[1]
```

This is the only thing I’ve gotten working so far, but now I realize it would be hard to generalize it for all the ships and all the coordinates.

I’ve also tried using the input as a string and checking if it’s ships, but it would always return false. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried. Also, have you considered using a dict instead of a list of lists?

Comment: since tuples are hashable, i would make your coordinates a set (not a list) of coordinates and do something like `if any(input in ship for ship in ships)` assuming that `ships` is a list of your sets and input is a coordinate tuple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you **have** to use lists:

```
ship1 = [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)]
ship2 = [(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)]
...

ships = [ship1, ship2, ... ]

shot = (3,5)

for ship in ships: 
  if shot in ship:
    hit...
    break
```

but as others have mentioned, a dict would probably be neater.

Comment: Clearly the better solution since it actually addresses the issue of using lists.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this might not be the answer you were looking for, but I would maybe set this up a bit differently to help yourself out. I'd set `ships` to be a dictionary where each ship serves as a key and the coordinates are a list of touples. It would look like this:

```
ships = {"ship1": [("7", "6"), ("2", "5"), ("3", "8")], "ship2": [and so on]}
guess = raw_input("What is your guess? ")
```

Now, without giving away too much of the game, your next step would be to loop through each ship in the dictionary and check if the guessed coordinates match any values for any of the ships.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) 2D array.

You can initialize your board to a zeros matrix and then mark the number of each ship in the appropriate rows and columns. Then to check which ship the user hit is very simple.

Small example:

```py
import numpy as np
# create board
board = np.zeros((8,8))
board[2:5,4] = 1
board[6,5:7] = 2
print(board)
# check shot
input = (2,4)
ship_num = board[input]
if ship_num != 0:
   print("hit!")
```

Comment: just use `board[input]`

Comment: @steabert - you are right, it's better. I edited my code.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at this backward. Don't check with the ships to see if they exist at the location that's being shot at, make the BOARD responsible for knowing where the ships are, reporting to the opponent that there was a hit, and reporting to the ship that it was shot.

```
class Board(list):
    def __init__(self, size, ships):
        for row in range(size):
            self.append([0] * size)

        self.ships = ships
        for ship in self.ships:
            # each ship is a list of tuples (column, row)
            for coord in ship:
                x, y = coord
                self[y][x] = ship  # store a reference to the ship at
                                   # each location the ship is in
    def check_hit(self, location):
        x, y = location
        if self[y][x]:
            # there's a ship here!
            ship = self[y][x]
            self[y][x] = 0  # don't report another hit at this location
            still_alive = ship.get_shot(location)
            # tell the ship it's been hit and ask it if it's still alive
            if still_alive:
                return Ship.ALIVE  # tell the caller that it hit something
            else:
                self.ships.remove(ship)
                return Ship.DEAD  # tell the caller it KILLED something
        else:
            return False  # you missed
```

Then your ship might be:

```
class Ship(object):
    ALIVE = 1
    DEAD = 2
    def __init__(self, type_, locations):
        self.type = type_  # battleship, destroyer, etc
        self.locations = locations

    @property
    def is_alive(self):
        return bool(self.locations)
        # is self.locations is empty, this is a dead ship!

    def get_hit(self, location):
        self.locations.remove(location)
        return self.is_alive
```